# Where did the constant go in o.d.e. $x' \sin t + x \cos t = 3 t^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an o.d.e. $x^{'}\sin(t)+x\cos(t)=3t^{2}$ and solve it: $(x \sin(t))'=3t^{2}$, $\int_0^{\tau}(x\sin(t))'dt=\int_0^{\tau}3t^{2}dt=   (t^{3}+c)|_{0}^{\tau}=\tau^{3}$.

Finally $x(\tau)\sin\tau=\tau^{3}$. Where did the constant go? It's o.d.e.,
there should be a constant. Where is a mistake? Please help.

Solution to question. It is known from general theory that the solution to the equation is not unique. As I was prompted in the comments by
Ivan Kaznacheyeu, my mistake was that I assumed that the solution at zero exists and general solution: $\frac{t^3}{\sin t} + C \frac{1}{\sin t}$. Apart from me, two people answered the question. According to their answers, it seems that there is only one solution. Their answers do not explain why the solution of the equation turned out to be unique if it is known that it cannot be unique. I wrote general solution and my answer has been deleted as a bad answer. It's not fair at all.

Comment: Your solution is not fully correct. You've used additional fact that solution $x(t)$ exists at $t=0$. If you will use the fact that solution exists at $t=15\pi$, you can get another solution. $15\pi$ is only number for example.

Comment: The general solution is $\frac{t^3-a}{\sin t}$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu, I understood, thank you !

Answer (score 3):

If you put $t=0$ in the DE you get $x'(0) (0)+x(0)(1)=0$ so $x(0)=0$. There is only one solution to this DE in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: does this mean there is no constant in my equation? I thought there is always a constant in the first order equation. So it’s not true?

Comment: There is no constant in this case. @SergeiNikolaev

Comment: I found my mistake. I assumed that the solution at zero exists and lost the constant $\frac{t^3}{\sin t} + C \frac{1}{\sin t}$.

Answer (score 0):

You have used limits, which are the same thing as initial and boundary conditions, so the constant disappears.

Comment: I found my mistake. I assumed that the solution at zero exists and lost the constant $\frac{t^3}{\sin t} + C \frac{1}{\sin t}$.